# app-router doesn't render template in Polymer

Tags: routes, polymer

I'm trying to use app-router for my routes but somehow I can't get it working... I've got a menu which successfully switches to the active state. However there is no content? What am I doing wrong?

**the empty DOM**

[image]

**app-router**

```
<app-router trailingSlash="ignore">
          <app-route path="/projects" import="/src/pages/view.html"></app-route>
          <app-route path="/admin" import="/src/pages/test.html"></app-route>
 </app-router>
```

**Template**

```
<polymer-element name="test" attributes="pathArg1 queryParam1" noscript>
<template>
   This is a test
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        domReady: function() {

            //attempt to create a template instance...
            var template = this.querySelector('template');
            var content = template.createInstance();
            this.appendChild(content);


        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you combine `app-route` with a `iron-pages` instead of manually importing the content ?

Comment: Why you use old version of Polymer?